# how spark select BroadcastExchange side

Tags: apache-spark

In my understanding, when Spark selects Broadcast Join, The side with a smaller physical data size will be broadcasted,

but today, use the same sql and table data, I've come across the opposite example, the pic as follow

the smaller table was broadcasted
[image: the smaller table was broadcasted]

the bigger table was broadcasted
[image: the bigger table was broadcasted]

so I want to know **how spark  select the broadcast side**, can anyone give me some help ?

Answer (score 0):

If default config is used, spark will not broadcast such a big table, its 2.8 GB is size. Most likely, someone called broadcast on the larger table in code and that's why spark is broadcasting it.

Can you also share the code snippet for the join, can help better then.